# Android Java TCP/IP server to service

Tags: java, android

I can not add TCP/IP Server to the service, when closing (minimizing) the application, the server does not accept data.
How to make the data transmitted continuously?

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    myServer = new Server();
    myServer.start();  
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}
```

Server

```
 private class Server extends Thread {
    private Socket clientSocket; 
    private  ServerSocket server; 
    private  BufferedReader in; 
    private  BufferedWriter out; 
    private String LOG_TAG;

    @Override
    public void run() {
      while (true) {
            try {
                server = new ServerSocket(9002);
                clientSocket = server.accept();
                try {
                    try {
                        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
                        out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream()));
                        String word = in.readLine();
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "***" + word + "***");
                        out.write(word);
                        out.flush();
                    } finally {
                        System.out.println("run closed");
                        clientSocket.close();
                        in.close();
                        out.close();
                    }
                } finally {
                    System.out.println("Server closed");
                    server.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So many problems with this code.  Here's a list of them:

- You'd need to be a foreground service, or Android will eventually kill your service.
- You're making a server socket and accepting a single connection to it, then making another in a loop.  That's not how you do it.  You make the server socket once, and accept() for each incoming connection
- As a consequence of the above, the second time will always fail, because the port won't be immediately available unless you use a socket with SO_REUSEADDR set.  see the setReuseAddress call on ServerSocket
- You're catching all exceptions blindly.  I would *highly* suspect you're throwing an exception and ignoring it, causing it all to not work
- This code won't work on any cellular network, as a NAT will be put between you and the world.
- Even on wifi you need to make sure your network allows incoming connections to your device.  The default on most home routers is not to.

Comment: Although the code is a curve, but it is working. Works on static IP. Can anyone have good an code to get data to the server in service?

Comment: https://github.com/umdomby/server/blob/master/server   
Bluetooth works in the background, and the server does not

Comment: It's nothing about being in the background that stops it from working for at least a short time. It's the network and the code itself

Comment: Well, if you do not know how to solve the problem, drive the air?